# Why were his vocal cords removed in Marvel's Agent Carter?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agent-carter

In the pilot episode of Marvel's Agent Carter, a man with his vocal cords removed was shown with a scar on his neck. Why were the vocal cords removed and why was the scar kept in such a way?

[image]

Comment: I would recommend updating your question then.

Comment: And "Green Suit" and Leet Brannis both have the scars. Since they were both connected to Leviathan at some point, the best guess anyone has at this point is that it was a result of that affiliation in some way.

Comment: I don't see the purpose in asking a question like this. It's clear that this is a deliberate part of the story. What makes you think it won't be answered by simply _watching the rest of the show_?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So was it answered ? :)

Comment: @JashJacob: Yes! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the show is still in its infancy, this question is impossible to answer at the moment. However, if I were to speculate, it may just be a way of showing how ruthless both Leviathan AND its operatives are. The group is so dedicated to keeping its secrets that it will remove the vocal cords of its own operatives. AND the operatives are so loyal to the ideals of Leviathan that they're willing to sacrifice their own vocal cords.

I may be wrong, given that a certain character without vocal cords seems to have changed his mind at the last moment, but that may also be the reason that Mr. Green-Suit was after him to begin with. As it is, we'll just have to wait and see.

**UPDATE:** As of the show's finale, we now have an answer to this question:

> The operatives in question are survivors of the Battle of Finow, and were thus exposed to the "Midnight Oil" gas accidentally invented by Howard Stark.